# Firefox page-break-after does not work

Tags: firefox, page-break

I have a an html model using `<div style="break-after:always;">`. It seems to have stopped working in Firefox 32.0.1. I can´t change mu html because it is a model already recorded in the database. How can I proceed?

Comment: This is why you should not store HTML in a database.  (and also why you should separate CSS & HTML)

Answer (score 0):

**Update** Firefox now supports the `break-after: always` declaration, as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after).

Previously,
[Firefox did not currently support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after) `break-after` so you'll need to use a polyfill if targeting old versions of Firefox.

One option is [this](https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-regions-polyfill).

Comment: Well, it does now ```page-break-after

Warning: This property has been replaced by the break-after property.
``` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after